# WordPress - Several Menulinks to same URL active

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

Im designing a big Dropdown-Menu with 2 Sub-Levels in the Divi WordPress Theme, where several menu-links are individual-links pointing to the same Page (the customer wants this). Now all of those links get an active class by default in WordPress once any link is clicked.
Is there an easy way around this without using jQuery?

I tried solving this using CSS, but I think Im missing something really basic in the WordPress settings.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a URL we can take a look at?